# problems with hooking to multiple wpf windows

Tags: c#, wpf, pointers, hook, keyboard-shortcuts

I need to add hooks to wpf windows for creating keyboard shortcuts to my application. 
I'm trying to get the window pointer from the Application class when it's activated, using the activated event. It works great when there's only one window.
We allow opening another window by pressing F11. This window opens in full screen mode and it can be closed only by pressing F11 or ESC. It seems like I can't get the correct pointer of this new window because all keyboard shortcuts don't work, except for F11 for some reason.
Code for getting pointer:

```
var windows = System.
Windows.Application. Current.Windows;
If (windows.Count < 1)
{
    return false;
}

else if (windows. Count ==1)
{
    winPointer = new WindowInteropHelper(windows[0]);
    return true;
}

else 
{
    for (int I = 0; I < windows. Count; I++)
    {
         if (windows [I].IsActive)
         winPointer =new WindowInteropHelper(windows[i]);
         .
         .
         .
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm missing something, but if you're opening a new window, why can't you capture the key down for that window and handle it that way?

```
    public partial class NewFullScreenWindow : Window
    {
        public NewFullScreenWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            KeyDown += HandleKeyDown;
        }

        private void HandleKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Escape || e.Key == Key.F11)
            {
                Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I get the keyboard events in another class, by hooking to the window. All shortcuts are common to all of the windows, so I don't use the window events and function directly

Comment: Are you using SetWindowsHookEx or with PInvoke or something then in your other classe?

Comment: I'm using HwndSource.AddHook function

Comment: If thats the case, then surely you can determine in the hook callback to check if its F11 or Esc and maybe tie that in with the IsFocused property on your Window

The code I have uses SetWindowsHookEx to create a global hook. Maybe look at doing that rather than tie the hook to the window itself